# Use of end = ' , ' to print values

Tags: python, matrix, printf

The "matriz" is this:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to output the "matriz in this form:

```
1, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0
```

So, I use the code shown here in Python:

```
for x in matriz:
    for y in x:
        print(y, end=',')
    print('')
```

However, I get an ' , ' of the end of each (not desired) line like this:

```
1, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0,
```

How can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to separate element of a list with the character you want

```py
for x in matriz:
    print(','.join(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sep parameter for items of each row and print rows in a loop:

```
for row in matriz: print(*row,sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

In print function there's `sep` statement other than `end`
It is used when you pass several object first.

```
for x in matriz:
    print(*x, sep=',')
```